# Getting the price from AppStore webhook

Tags: app-store

I accept webhooks from AppStore, but I'm wondering why there's no price the user paid for the subscription? I mean in transaction info [JWSTransactionDecodedPayload](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreservernotifications/jwstransactiondecodedpayload). Also I couldn't find any other API methods to get the price.

The reason I need the price, because there may be different cost and commission the customer has to pay, depending on his country or something else.

Answer (score 0):

We can only get the price from client with [SKProduct](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skproduct) in Original StoreKit by [SKProductsRequest](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/skproductsrequest), or with [Product](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/product) in StoreKit 2 by [products(for:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/product/3851116-products) for now.

Or we get the price from App Store Connect with ProductID configured on Apple. However, price currency is related with AppleID, means we also need currency to confirm how much user paid.

I think why receipt not contains price is also for this reason. Apple could not represent all prices with different currency in a receipt, so only provide ProductID for us to query.

Answer (score 0):

Apple [added](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreservernotifications/jwstransactiondecodedpayload) the `price` and `currency` properties in the `JWSTransactionDecodedPayload` object, this makes working with prices much easier. Still, if you don't want to hassle with building your subscription logic, try Adapty, it does the whole building part for you.